# Axis: getting java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: Bad version number in .class file

Tags: java, web-services, axis

I've been getting this error several times, and preceeding it I'm also getting:

> [JavaUtils] Unable to find required classes
>   (javax.activation.DataHandler and javax.mail.internet.MimeMultipart).
>   Attachment support is disabled

I've added activation.jar and mail.jar to my classpath but it's no good. Could anybody help me with this.

Thanks in advance,

PS: The issue occurs when invoking a certain web-services.

EDIT: After deploying the project and trying to acces ws for the first time I got the exception, then, invoking the ws again does not cause any exception throwing. This is getting very weird.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error in your subject line happens when you try to use .class files compiled with the compiler for Java version X with the runtime for java version Y, X>Y. You need to use a more recent runtime, or you need to 'compile down' with the appropriate options to javac.

Comment: Thanks bmargulies for your answer. Concerning to this I've compiled with Java 1.5 and my runtime version is 1.5. I'm compiling from Eclipse (when I type java -version it's indeed 1.6, but I'm not compiling from commmand line).

Comment: Well, that's not what Java thinks. Are you sure that in your eclipse project options you've set the versions to 1.5? An alternative here is an entirely corrupt .class file.

Comment: Thanks, but I've already checked that. Perhaps it's something to do with axis version.

Comment: It's remotely possible that Axis got itself built with 1.6 or even 1.7.

Comment: I'm not talinkg about axis getting rebuilt, but being built with a java version that is previous to 1.5. I'm using axis 1.4